# Google is still indexing the old URLs after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have included the following in my .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex home.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^editprofile/(.+)$ editprofile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^designerprojects/(.+)$ designerprojects.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^favourites/(.+)$ designerfavourites.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^following/(.+)$ designerfollowing.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^followers/(.+)$ designerfollowers.php?username=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^projects/(.+)/(.+)$ projects.php?category_slug=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^editproject/(.+)/(.+)$ editprojects.php?category_slug=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^projects/(.+)$ view.php?category_slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^projects$ view.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/archives/(.+)$ archives.php?archive_slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)/(.+)$ post.php?category_name=$1&post_slug=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ category.php?category_slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^help/(.+)$ help.php?title_slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^help$ help.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^competitions/(.+)$ competitioninfo.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^competitions$ competitions.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mysite.com/404

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

The problem I am facing is that Google is still indexing the old URLs and it has been approx 1 month now.

Reading up on other posts I have tried changing the last line to read

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [R=301,L,QSA]
```

but that causes a lot of my links to be broken.

Please could somebody shed some light on where I may be going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You want the URLs to 301 redirect to the new URLs.  When you say the links are broken, are they redirecting improperly or are they throwing server errors?

Comment: Just because it has been a month+ doesn't mean that google has revisited the site in that timeframe.  Look at the `cached` version that google has and check `It is a snapshot of the page as it appeared on ...`

Comment: @dethtron5000 - Sorry yes I should have been more clear, with the R=301 they are redirecting improperly. For example a link to my terms page when testing should be http://localhost/lwim/terms but when you click on a link for this is goes to http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/lwim/terms.php (I have just tried this by going to http://localhost/lwim/terms.php and it works fine. (This is with the R=301 part in

Comment: How about modifying robots.txt file so that google does not index the files you do not want to be indexed?  You could also use webmaster tools to request a reindex of the site.